# im having difficulty with normals

Tags: uv, normals, baking, uv-image-editor

i have a character in a lot of detailed, however has just under 300,000 faces,[image]

i want to place it onto a backup model before it was detailed which has 9000 faces,

[image]
so pretty low poly compared, i have looked up tutorials on normal and went through step by step 2 different tutorials but im having no luck baking the normal onto the low poly copy, on the uv map, its complete black, and doesn't change into the backed uv and just stays black, i did all the shader editor nodes correctly but im just not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: Has the lowpoly model a UV map?

Comment: could you elaborate sorry?  in the tutorials it told me to smart uv the mesh where that black box should be

Comment: This is what I meant. Smart UV project creates a UV map. I just wonder why your map is black. Had you unplugged the Image texture node when you baked it? Is there a message in the status bar?

Comment: no i hadnt, for some reason, cause i tried it a few times, when you hover over some of the textures you make, it shows a small preview image, and the preview image looks like the finished product, but odiously when its selected its the same as the other attempts, tell me if im wrong, i went into my editor, selected all vertices on my low poly, clicked uv, and selected smart uv project, is this the correct smart uv, or are there multiple as in the tutorials it tells you to click u on your keyboard but that doesn't wok for me so i selected the uv options on the editor itself.

Comment: Make sure the image texture node is disconnected from the normal map node when you bake. Else you get a circular dependency error. The message disappeares after a few seconds. If it's successful, there is a progress bar and whem it's finished there is a reminder in the status bar that you need to save the baked image. -- yes, that's correct. You can press U when the mouse is in the 3D viewport (right side) for the Unwrap context menu. It's the same as the UV menu.

Comment: its telling me circular dependency for image "backup" from object "backup plain datum body"

Comment: That's the reason. Do you see the orange node and the purple node on the screenshots? They are connected. Remove the connection. Click the orange node (that's the Image Texture node) so it is highlighted. This tells Blender that you want to bake this image. Then  try again, select the objects, lowpoly must be selected last, and then bake it. When it's baked successfully you can connect the nodes again.

Comment: hi, i noticed that it works really well, why does the texture turn black however on certain areas cause on legs and bits of heads, it doesn't look god and turns black